# How to change specific words in RegEx

Tags: regex, replace, transform

On page https://regex101.com/

Regular expression:

```
(?<Path>.*[/\\])?(?<Name>.+?)(?<Ext>\..+)\s(?<Ext2>\[.+)
```

Text string:

```
c:\data\dispatchPS.vb [Design]
```

[image: Match information]

The goal:

Transform 3 different input strings like this:

- c:\data\dispatchPS.vb [Design] -> .vb.[D]
- c:\data\dispatchPS.vb -> .vb
- c:\data\dispatchPS.Designer.vb -> .D.vb

Comment: What is the tool or language? Where does this `D` char come from in the replacement?

Comment: its an extension in Visual Studio - Tabs Studio. And the language should be .NET (C#). The D char is an abbreviation from Design and Designer

Comment: Try something [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0vGSZ/1).

Comment: well bobble bubble, it works great on that link, but not in extension in VS. What could be wrong? Maybe another version of regex or what?

Comment: my bad, it works great. The bug was, that I didn't notice that the extension removes path itself. So the final correct regex expression was:

\w+(?:(\.\w)\w+)?(\.\w+)(?: (\[\w)\w*(\]))?

Thank You a lot

Answer (score 0):

So the final correct regex expression was:

```
\w+(?:(\.\w)\w+)?(\.\w+)(?: ([\w)\w*(]))?
```

Thanks, bobble bubble

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).